# Plot several graphs with one y-axis and another graph with a different y-axis on the same figure in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have three data sets and also a vector of their error. I want to plot them on the same figure, where the data sets are on the same y-axis (on the left) and the error is on the same figure but with a different axis (on the right).

The function [plotyy](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html) allows to do it for 1 plot on each axis, how do I do it for several plots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is also possible to use `plotyy()` with multiple rows of y-values.

Following an example from the matlab help:

```
x = 0:0.01:20;
y1 = [200*exp(-0.05*x).*sin(x);
      300*exp(-0.04*x).*sin(x)];
y2 = [0.8*exp(-0.5*x).*sin(10*x);
      0.6*exp(-0.4*x).*sin(5*x)];
[AX,H1,H2] = plotyy(x,y1,x,y2);

set(get(AX(1),'Ylabel'),'String','Slow Decay') 
set(get(AX(2),'Ylabel'),'String','Fast Decay') 

xlabel('Time (\musec)') 
title('Multiple Decay Rates')

set(H1,'LineStyle','--')
set(H2,'LineStyle',':')
```

producing the following figure

[image: Using plotyy with multiple y-values.]

Answer (score 4):

I think you should create the new `axes` manually:

```
figure(1); clf, hold on

x1 = 0:0.1:5*pi;
y1 = sin(x1)./x1;

x2 = 0:0.1:5*pi;
y2 = x2.^(0.2);

x3 = 0:0.1:5*pi;
y3 = cos(x3);

plot(x1,y1, 'b', 'linewidth', 2)
plot(x2,y2, 'g', 'linewidth', 2)
plot(x3,y3, 'k', 'linewidth', 2)


ax1 = gca;
ax2 = axes('Position', get(ax1,'Position'),...           
           'YAxisLocation','right',...
           'Color' , 'none',...
           'YColor', 'r');
linkaxes([ax1 ax2], 'x')

x4 = x3;
y4 = 0.025*randn(size(y3));

line(x4, y4, 'color', 'r', 'parent', ax2)
```

Output: 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code using Waterloo as suggested by @natan

```
x = 0:0.01:20;
y1 = [200*exp(-0.05*x).*sin(x);300*exp(-0.04*x).*sin(x)];
y2 = [0.8*exp(-0.5*x).*sin(10*x);0.6*exp(-0.4*x).*sin(5*x)];
f=GXFigure();
ax=subplot(f,1,1,1);
p1=line(ax, x, y1(1,:), 'LineColor', 'SEAGREEN');
p2=line(p1, [], y1(2,:), 'LineColor', 'TOMATO');
ax.getObject().getView().setXLabel(sprintf('Time Slow Decay %cs', char(181)));
layer1=kcl.waterloo.graphics.GJGraph.createInstance();
ax.getObject().getView().add(layer1);
p3=line(wwrap(layer1), x, y2(1,:), 'LineColor', 'CORNFLOWERBLUE');
p4=line(p3, x, y2(2,:), 'LineColor', 'CRIMSON');
layer1.setXLabel(sprintf('Time Fast Decay %cs', char(181)));
ax.getObject().setTitleText('Multiple Decay Rates');
```

which produces:

[image]

For other examples see  [here](http://waterloo.sourceforge.net/plotgallery.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here's something you can try:

```
% Example data
x = [1 2 3];
yd1 = [1 1 1];
yd2 = [2 2 2];
yd3 = [3 3 3];
ye1 = [0.1 0.2 0.3];
ye2 = [0.2 0.3 0.4];
ye3 = [0.3 0.4 0.5];
% Create two axes
ax1 = axes();
ax2 = axes();
% Plot your data
line(x, yd1, 'Parent', ax1, 'Color', 'b');
line(x, yd2, 'Parent', ax1, 'Color', 'b');
line(x, yd3, 'Parent', ax1, 'Color', 'b');
line(x, ye1, 'Parent', ax2, 'Color', 'r');
line(x, ye2, 'Parent', ax2, 'Color', 'r');
line(x, ye3, 'Parent', ax2, 'Color', 'r');
% Modify axes properties
set(ax1, 'ylim', [-10 4]);
set(ax2, 'Color', 'none', 'YAxisLocation', 'right', 'XTick', []);
```

[image]

I have used `line` instead of `plot`, because `plot` gives me some
issues with the y-axis ticks. More information [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/using-multiple-x-and-y-axes.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way to plot two y axes that allow you to use the same labeling and bounds setters as in normal plotting: `ylim`, `ylabel`, etc.

From the [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/plotting-with-two-y-axes.html).

```
yyaxis left;
plot(x, y_left);
ylim([0, 100]); % sets the limits for the left y axis
ylabel('left axis');

yyaxis right;
plot(x, y_right);
ylim([0, 100]); % sets the limits for the right y axis
ylabel('right axis');
```